# Contextual filter for taxonomy terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I have a taxonomy terms display that list a taxonomy_list, this taxonomy_list has parents and childs:

```
Parent
 child
Parent
 child
 child
```

Is there a contextual filter in views that i can use to pass the parent id and it would return the childs under this parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "**Taxonomy term: Parent term**" as contextual filter in your view.

Most likely you will need to provide a default value for the filter, such as "**Taxonomy term ID from URL**".

Provide a default value for your filter according to your preferred usage. The options for setting the default value of the filter should be self-explanatory.

Since you didn't specify where this view is supposed to be displayed, I can't give any other insight.